# Direct speech and indirect speech

Tags: reported-speech

Mahesh: What are you doing here?

Krishna: I am searching for my rank on the notice book.

Change into reported speech

Comment: Mahesh asked Krishna what he was doing here  Krishna replied that he was searching for his rank on the notice board

Comment: Are you asking us for an answer or commanding us?

Comment: @VenkatGolamari Likely the report of the speech isn't near the notice book where the exchange took place, so "what he was doing **there**." LIkewise if Krishna had said "on *this* notice book," the indirect version would be "on ***that*** notice book."

Comment: They can be standing in front of the notice board. NOT book.

Comment: -1. This appears to be a textbook/assignment question, and the post does not discuss any previous efforts to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The indirect speech would be:
*Mahesh asked Krishna what he was doing **there**. Krishna replied that he was searching for his rank on the notice board*

Answer (score 0):

If at the time Venkat was standing by the notice board in question it would be

> Mahesh asked Krishna what he was doing here and he replied that he was searching for his rank on the notice board.

If Venkat was anywhere else

> Mahesh asked Krishna what he was doing by the notice board and he replied that he was searching for his rank.

It is not necessary in context to repeat Krishna although it would not be wrong to do so.